# iOS build turns transparent pixels white

Tags: unity-game-engine

When starting my app on iOS all my buttons and all sprites that have any transparency have white outlines and white pixels outside of them.

This problem only occurs on iOS not on Android. I am using Unity 2019.4.34f1.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Do you use a custom shader for UI elements?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it's caused by an Unity Bug that cause iOS UI display transparency incorrectly in Light Mode. It has been fixed in the latest version of unity.

Related Forum Post:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-lightmode-bug-filed.1203829/